# ReGex with Python cant find the correct Regular Expression

Tags: python-2.7, helper, web-clips

I'm trying to extract some text out of a poorly design web page for a project, and after a long research and learning python I came close to make it happen, but the web page is poorly designed and can't find the right regular expression to do it.

So here we have what I've accomplished. http://coj.uci.cu/24h/status.xhtml?username=Diego1149&abb=1006 out of the source code of this web page I want to get the whole line of the first instance of an accepted problem. So I thought of this

```
exprespatFinderTitle = re.compile('<table id="submission" class="volume">.*(<tr class=.*>.*<label class="AC">.*Accepted.*</label>.*</tr>).*</table>')
```

but what does this does is clipping up until the last `<tr>` of the table. Can someone help me figure this out?

Im using Python 2.7 whit BeautifulSoup and urllib

Comment: If you are using BeautifulSoup, *why* are you using regular expressions still?

Comment: I've tried using BeautifulSoup but I came closer with regular expressions. Would it help if I post my source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick to BeautitfulSoup alone; regular expressions are *not* the tool for HTML parsing:

```
table = soup.find('table', id='submission')
accepted = table.tbody.find('label', class_='AC')
if accepted:
    row = accepted.parent.parent  # row with accepted column
```

Comment: Well, thank you very much, this really helped I've been trying to figure this out for like 8 hours in a row now. Got to thank you again :)